# How to multiply (double) arrows in Jssor Slider

Tags: jssor

**Hi!**
If i multiply left and right arrows they stop working.
How to fix this?
I want to have 4 arrows 2(left)+2(right):
**IMAGE**: http://cdn.joxi.ru/uploads/prod/2014/06/04/29b/361/cf019c0d8b14cf6e70b17f613ca00b78285f0bfd.png


Tnks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add arrows for thumbnail navigator.

See [slider with 4 arrows](http://www.jssor.com/testcase/slider-with-4-arrows.source.html) demo

Reference http://www.jssor.com/demos-jquery/thumbnail-navigator-with-arrows.source.html